# GAE Python: how get last modified date of static file

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm adding some static files to my Python app on Google app engine. I do it like this, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles).

app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

I put my files in the subdirectory stylesheets within the my_project_app folder.

How can I get the last modified date of a file in stylesheets?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that getting a last-modified date might help?

Comment: I add it as a parameter to my static files to handle caching: my_js.js?v=201508072024.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple make static files accessible that is all.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

> application_readable
>
> Optional. By default, files declared in static file handlers are
>   uploaded as static data and are only served to end users, they cannot
>   be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the files are
>   also uploaded as code data so your application can read them. Both
>   uploads are charged against your code and static data storage resource
>   quotas.

use such code to locate file relative to python file - sometimes you need `..` to go up.

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'template', 'list_tbody_part.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you indicate the a file or directory is static by default you can not access it with your application, which means you can't get the modification date. You can think of the static files as being uploaded to a different machine that is configured to to serve static files.

You can upload the file both as a static file and an application resource (or use a symlink), but this means it counts twice against the quota. Recently this has been made easier with the addition of the `application_readable` option. Setting it to `true` in `app.yaml`  essentially does the same thing. (see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers ).

Once your application can read the file you can use the standard `os` library to read the whatever information you need.